# PHP shell_exec() - Verbose Output?

Tags: php, command-line, codeception

I have a Codeigniter project that uses Codeception for acceptance testing. I have a 'tools' controller setup in Codeigniter, which I use to store command line methods that perform various utility functions.

In this case, I'm creating a utility method that sets up the testing environment, switches databases, builds / runs the tests, etc.

I'm using the PHP function `shell_exec()` to run the codception commands.  They're working, however when `shell_exec()` issues the `php codecept.phar run' command, it's not providing verbose output.  It waits until all the tests are done (which takes a long time) and then spits out all the output at the end.

Is there a way to have shell_exec() print the output as it receives it?

example code:

```
public function run_tests() 
{ 
     $this->load->database('testing'); 
     echo shell_exec("cd ..; php codecept.phar build"); 
     echo shell_exec("cd ..; php codecept.phar run"); 
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: excellent, works great.  Post this as an answer to I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php), which streams the output of a command directly to the response stream.

Comment: For some reason I am losing terminal/shell color codes on `passthru()`